# CALL WCF(REST ot SOAP) from MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, soap

I need to create a MVC project that calls a WCF service. MVC project needs to only pass data to Service(service is going to connect to database and get data and do all the data manipulation) and then return the result to MVC project. I need to know when I want to start the WCF service, is it any preferences to have a REST or SOAP. Is there any of these services connect better with MVC project? also do you have any tutorial show me how to call a service in MVC.

Comment: I would recommend using REST. You can write this either as a WCF service or as a WebApi website. The you call the service with HttpClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using service on server side then you can use REST or SOAP Service. If you are using AngularJS or similar Frameworks then use REST API.